# How to get 1/0 values (by conditions) for variables that created from another data frame? (pandas/numpy)

Tags: pandas

I'v got two data frames, let's say 'df1' and 'df2'.
In 'df1' there are three variables: 'X', 'Y', 'Z'.
'X' and 'Y' indicates ID's, I did calculation (no matter which) for each pair (X,Y) and got 'Z' variable.

In 'df2' there are two variables: 'Y', 'W'.
'Y' is the same ID that mentioned before in 'df1',
and 'W' is some other variable (no matter what).

Now, I want to create (with pandas) variables in 'df2' which are the 'X' ID's in 'df1',
and for each variable that created, to get value "1" for each row in 'df2', if the 'Z' value for the specific pair (X,Y) is equal or greater than "4" ( >= 4), and (&) the specific 'W' value equal or greater than "5" ( >= 5), "0" otherwise.

This is demonstration of the data frames:

df1:

```
X   Y   Z
1   a   1
1   b   9
1   c   4
2   a   1
2   b   7
2   c   3
3   a   4
3   b   3
3   c   6
```

df2:

```
Y   W
a   7
a   3
b   5
b   7
b   2
c   6
c   9
c   4
c   8
```

Expected result (df2):

```
Y   W   1   2   3
a   7   0   0   1
a   3   0   0   0
b   5   1   1   0
b   7   1   1   0
b   2   0   0   0
c   6   1   0   1
c   9   1   0   1
c   4   0   0   0
c   8   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes together on column `Y`. Then we [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) the `X` values to columns. Finally we use `DataFrame.filter` to get the correct columns and use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally apply your logic to get the `1` and `0` in the columns:

```
new = df2.merge(df1,on='Y').pivot_table(index=['Y', 'W'], columns='X', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
new.columns = [c1 if c2 == '' else str(c2) for c1, c2 in new.columns]

for col in new.filter(regex='\d$').columns:
    new[col] = np.where(new['W'].ge(5) & new[col].ge(4),1,0)
```

**Output**

```
   Y  W  1  2  3
0  a  3  0  0  0
1  a  7  0  0  1
2  b  2  0  0  0
3  b  5  1  1  0
4  b  7  1  1  0
5  c  4  0  0  0
6  c  6  1  0  1
7  c  8  1  0  1
8  c  9  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you Erfan! It helped me.